# How to fill "ion-checkbox ng-repeat" at the time of page load

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

**What I need to do?**
I am trying to load the `"ion-checkbox ng-repeat"` `"onDeviceReady"` automatically at the time of page load. Below is the HTML code.

```
        <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="item in devList"
        ng-model="item.checked"
        ng-checked="item.checked">
        {{ item.text }}
        </ion-checkbox>
```

But the `"ion-checkbox ng-repeat"` is getting loaded only when click event is triggered. 
The below is the angular-js code which needs to be triggered automaticlly at the time of page load.

**Problem:** The data for "ion-checkbox ng-repeat" is not getting filled at the time of page load. 
Can anyone help to solve the issue.

```
  angular.module('app', ['ionic'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.devList = [];
window.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
        function onDeviceReady() {
        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter = "";      // empty search string returns all contacts
        options.multiple = true;  // return multiple results
        filter = ["*"]; // return contact.displayName field
        //document.getElementById("lan").innerHTML = lan;
        // find contacts
        navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);

        }
        function onSuccess(contacts) {

        for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {

        $scope.devList[i] = {text:""+contacts[i].name.formatted, emails:{email:""+contacts[i].emails[0].value,checked:false}, phno:{phone:""+contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value,checked:false},addres:{address: contacts[i].addresses||[],checked:false},checked: false};
        $scope.emails[i] = {email:""+contacts[i].emails[0].value+""};
        }

        }
        function onError(contactError) {
        alert('onError!');
        }

}
```

Comment: Did you check `ondeviceready` is loaded properly

Comment: @shammon ondeviceready is getting loaded properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to call $apply if you do anything outside of angular context**

```
 function onSuccess(contacts) {

        for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {

        $scope.devList[i] = {text:""+contacts[i].name.formatted, emails:{email:""+contacts[i].emails[0].value,checked:false}, phno:{phone:""+contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value,checked:false},addres:{address: contacts[i].addresses||[],checked:false},checked: false};
        $scope.emails[i] = {email:""+contacts[i].emails[0].value+""};
        $scope.$apply();
        }

        }
```